# Can you compress strings in the frontend and send it to the backend as a BLOB?

Tags: reactjs, compression, tinymce, blob, form-data

I'm working on an app that can save the file created with tinyMCE, the problem is that I want to compress the given html (in case there's a lot of text) so that i can send it to the backend as a binary data (blob). The problem is that when I print the size of the text and of the compressed file the compressed file is bigger than the normal text. I don't know that much of compression but I know that if some files are already compressed, if you zip them they can be larger. How does this apply in html or strings?

I'm using JSZip for compression and I send it as a form data into the backend.

Here's the code for the button that triggers the saving of the file:
(The content can be something like `<p>saacasdsafsafsafsafasfsafsafasfsafsafasfasfasfsaasfasfasfsafasfasfassasss123</p>`, a html tag)

```js
<button onClick={async ()=>{
                console.log(editorRef.current.getContent());
                const content = editorRef.current.getContent();
                const zip = new JSZip();
                zip.file('content.txt', content);
                const blob = await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
                const blobSize = blob.size;
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file_content', blob);

                console.log('Initial Size of Text:', (new TextEncoder().encode(editorRef.current.getContent())).length, 'bytes');
                console.log('Size after Zipping:', blobSize, 'bytes');

                axios.post('http://localhost:3001/files/save', formData)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('File saved successfully. Response:', response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error saving file:', error);
                });
            }}>save</button>
```